# Objects don't touch when they collide?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to get a couple asteroids to collide, however they collide without touching each other. How do I go about getting them to collide when closer together, or actually touching?

[image]

[image]

Tried changing the collision margin to no effect.

[image]

Comment: Try to change shape from Convex Hull to Mesh

Comment: That did the trick thank you, you can make an answer if you want and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable accurate object collision, in Physics tab change Collision Shape of the rigid body to **Mesh** instead of default **Convex Hull.**

[image]