# Rigid body objects intersecting

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a box with a mesh active rigid body applied to it sitting on top of a character that has the same settings. The box will not act like a solid object and continues to intersect with the characters body. What is going on?

In the image you see his arm poking out the side of the box instead of the box sitting on top of his arm.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objects don't touch when they collide?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30957/objects-dont-touch-when-they-collide)

Comment: In Rigid Body Collision change the Shape from Convex Hull to Mesh

Comment: @Denis no that's not it. The character changed to mesh only causes more issues. The box already has mesh applied as stated in the question.

Comment: From the screenshot I was assuming that it was Convex Hull, can you add the blend file?